# How to add input to array without deleting the previous in JS?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to collect user input into array but everytime i do the previous is being replaced.Here is my code

```
  let inputValue = input.value;
  let inputArray = [];
  inputArray.push(inputValue);
  console.log(inputArray);
```

Comment: Move let inputArray = []; , outside the function. It should be initialized only once.

Comment: everytime you are redeclaring the array as []. Only push within the function or event handler

Answer (score 3):

Your declaring your inputArray as empty all the time, if you have that code inside a function scope like this:

```
function collectUserInput() {
  let inputValue = input.value;
  let inputArray = [];
  inputArray.push(inputValue);
  console.log(inputArray);
}
```

you need to declare the inputArray outside the function so evertyme you call the ollectUserInput you add one more input to the pre-existing array, like this:

```
let inputArray = [];

function collectUserInput() {
  let inputValue = input.value;
  inputArray.push(inputValue);
  console.log(inputArray);
}
```